# Hibernate Many To Many association +join table+extra column update is not working properly

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I am taking an example.I have an Employee Class that has many to many relationship with Address Class.I am using composite key to insert data in my join table which has one extra column city.

My All Pojos are

//Employee Class

```
package com.test.manyToMany;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;

import org.hibernate.annotations.Cascade;
import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;

@Entity(name="EMPLOYEE")
public class Employee {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private List<EmployeeAddress> employeeAddress;

    @Id
    @GenericGenerator(name="generator",strategy="increment")
    @GeneratedValue(generator="generator")
    @Column(name="ID",nullable=false,unique=true)
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name="NAME")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY,mappedBy="pk.employee")
     @Cascade({org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE, 
            org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN})
    public List<EmployeeAddress> getEmployeeAddress() {
        return employeeAddress;
    }
    public void setEmployeeAddress(List<EmployeeAddress> employeeAddress) {
        this.employeeAddress = employeeAddress;
    }

}
```

//Address Class

```
package com.test.manyToMany;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;

import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;

@Entity(name="ADDRESS")
public class Address {

    private int id;
    private String place;
    private List<EmployeeAddress> employeeAddress;

    @Id
    @GenericGenerator(name="generator",strategy="increment")
    @GeneratedValue(generator="generator")
    @Column(name="ID")
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name="PLACE")
    public String getPlace() {
        return place;
    }
    public void setPlace(String place) {
        this.place = place;
    }

    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY,mappedBy="pk.address")
    public List<EmployeeAddress> getEmployeeAddress() {
        return employeeAddress;
    }

    public void setEmployeeAddress(List<EmployeeAddress> employeeAddress) {
        this.employeeAddress = employeeAddress;
    }
}
```

//Employee Address

```
package com.test.manyToMany;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.AssociationOverride;
import javax.persistence.AssociationOverrides;
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.EmbeddedId;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Transient;


@Entity
@Table(name="EMPLOYEE_T_ADDRESS")
@AssociationOverrides({
    @AssociationOverride(name="pk.employee",
            joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="EMPLOYEE_ID")),
    @AssociationOverride(name="pk.address",
            joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="ADDRESS_ID"))})
public class EmployeeAddress implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4050660680047579957L;
    private EmployeeAddressId pk=new EmployeeAddressId();
    private String city;

    @EmbeddedId
    public EmployeeAddressId getPk() {
        return pk;
    }

    @Transient
    public Employee getEmployee() {
        System.out.println("Primary Key:"+getPk());
        return getPk().getEmployee();
    }

    public void setEmployee(Employee employee) {
        getPk().setEmployee(employee);
    }

    @Transient
    public Address getAddress() {
        System.out.println("Primary Key1:"+getPk());
        return getPk().getAddress();
    }

    public void setAddress(Address address) {
        getPk().setAddress(address);
    }

    public void setPk(EmployeeAddressId pk) {
        this.pk = pk;
    }

    @Column(name="CITY",length=50)
    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }
    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((city == null) ? 0 : city.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((pk == null) ? 0 : pk.hashCode());
        return result;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        EmployeeAddress other = (EmployeeAddress) obj;
        if (city == null) {
            if (other.city != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!city.equals(other.city))
            return false;
        if (pk == null) {
            if (other.pk != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!pk.equals(other.pk))
            return false;
        return true;
    }   

}
```

//EmployeeAddressId

```
package com.test.manyToMany;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Embeddable;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;

@Embeddable
public class EmployeeAddressId implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -9120607274421816301L;
    private Employee employee;
    private Address address;

    @ManyToOne
    public Employee getEmployee() {
        return employee;
    }
    public void setEmployee(Employee employee) {
        this.employee = employee;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    public Address getAddress() {
        return address;
    }
    public void setAddress(Address address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((address == null) ? 0 : address.hashCode());
        result = prime * result
                + ((employee == null) ? 0 : employee.hashCode());
        return result;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        EmployeeAddressId other = (EmployeeAddressId) obj;
        if (address == null) {
            if (other.address != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!address.equals(other.address))
            return false;
        if (employee == null) {
            if (other.employee != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!employee.equals(other.employee))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

}
```

When i am inserting some data in db using my main class and Everything is working fine.

```
package com.test.manyToMany;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.hibernate.Session;

import com.test.utils.HibernateUtil;

public class TestManyToMany {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Session session=HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();

        Employee employee1=new Employee();
        EmployeeAddress employeeAddress=new EmployeeAddress();
        Address address=new Address();
        ArrayList<EmployeeAddress> list=new ArrayList<EmployeeAddress>();
        address.setId(1);

        employee1.setName("XYZ");
        employeeAddress.setCity("CDE");
        employeeAddress.setEmployee(employee1);
        employeeAddress.setAddress(address);
        list.add(employeeAddress);
        employee1.setEmployeeAddress(list);

        session.save(employee1);
        session.getTransaction().commit();

    }

}
```

But when i am updating the same record with address id 2.

```
package com.test.manyToMany;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.hibernate.Session;

import com.test.utils.HibernateUtil;

public class TestManyToMany {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Session session=HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();

        Employee employee1=new Employee();
        EmployeeAddress employeeAddress=new EmployeeAddress();
        Address address=new Address();
        ArrayList<EmployeeAddress> list=new ArrayList<EmployeeAddress>();
        address.setId(2);
        //session.save(address);
        employee1.setId(1);
        employee1.setName("XYZ");
        employeeAddress.setCity("CDE");
        employeeAddress.setEmployee(employee1);
        employeeAddress.setAddress(address);
        list.add(employeeAddress);
        employee1.setEmployeeAddress(list);
        //address.setEmployeeAddress(list);
        //session.save(employee1);


        session.update(employee1);
        session.getTransaction().commit();

    }

}
```

My join table is not deleting the first record that is

```
+-----------+----------+----+
|EMPLOYEE_ID|ADDRESS_ID|CITY|
+-----------+----------+----+
| 1         |     1    |CDE |
+-----------+----------+----+
```

it is inserting the second record also

```
+-----------+----------+----+
|EMPLOYEE_ID|ADDRESS_ID|CITY|
+-----------+----------+----+
| 1         |     1    |CDE |
+-----------+----------+----+
|1          |     2    |CDE |
+-----------+----------+----+
```

my fist record should be deleted then it should insert the second record.which is not happening.

Comment: Hi Raman, When you create the employee object using constructor are you intending to create a new employee entity or you want to load an existing employee entity ? if you want to update Addresses for existing entity you should use session.load(pk) and get the object, before modifying the Address list.

Comment: I am updating existing employee only.But i am giving same id to employee object.problem is Hibernate should delete the my first record which is not happening.It may be because of composite key.Because when i am editing my city to CDE1 with same employee_id 1 and address_id 1 then it's working fine and hibernate is updating my city to CDE1.